# Finding duplicate string from a list( contains 5 million strings ) without "Out of Memory" Error

Tags: java, string, duplicates

I have to check whether a string is already picked up from a data source or not. I can use HashMap but as the number of key's are large so it may cause out of memory error. 
So what is the best way to find duplicate from 5 million strings?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about a db?

Comment: use multi thread and find each 100K frame windows in list

Comment: @ScaryWombat but I read this string from a file and separate the duplicate and after that insert in database.

Comment: @gifpif, using multi thread won't reduce the memory usage at all, but complicated the thing when reading a file using multiple threads.

Comment: @atulkumar, using a temporary db table to store all the strings. Then use SQL to find number of occurrences of each string and insert into your actual table.

Comment: @Alex thanks for you suggestion. But to store each string in temporary db may increase time complexity. Isn't it?

Comment: @atulkumar The reading and inserting into temporary db is just O(n). However, I don't know how to calculate the time complexity of database select SQL.

Comment: @Alex there's no need to make things complicated by counting occurrences. The simplest and most efficient way is to dump them in a table, then dump them into another table with `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: @Kayaman I know we can deduplicate by using `SELECT DISTINCT`. However, seems that the OP wants to find duplicated ones.

Comment: @Alex that's what his question states, but his first comment seems to imply that he just wants to deduplicate the data. Possibly he doesn't understand that there's no need to *find* occurrences for that, and he was trying to implement some really poor deduplication algorithm.

Comment: @Kayaman, ar yes, you're right.

Comment: If you were going to do this with a database, you wouldn't use `SELECT DISTINCT`, you'd use a `GROUP BY` followed by `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`.

Comment: So without using database can I use hasmap in different way?

Comment: Yes. My answer tells you how.

Comment: Thanks every one.. I will try to implement in the way @DawoodibnKareem wrote..

Comment: Do you want to remove the duplicates, or keep only those with duplicates?

Comment: @Kayaman I want to separate the duplicate in another array.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Please see my updated question.

Comment: So?  Is this a different question now?  What are you asking me for?

Answer (score 2):

Without giving you code, here's a rough algorithm for doing it.

Make one pass through the input file, calculating the hash code for each String.  Store these hash codes in a HashMap, where the key is each String's hash code and the value is the number of times that hash code has been found.  At this point, you're not storing the Strings themselves - only the hash codes.

Now iterate through the HashMap, deleting any entries where the value (that is, the count associated with the hash code) is 1.  Now you have a map whose keys are all hash codes that have appeared more than once in the file.  Most of these will be "hash collisions", but if there are duplicated Strings in the file, their hash codes will be in the map.

Lastly, iterate through the file again.  For each String, check whether its hash code is in the map that you prepared earlier.  If the hash code is present, then add the String to a Set.  If the String was already in the Set, then you've found your duplicate.  If the hash code was not present in the map, just drop the String because you know it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Then their hash codes end up in the map after the first pass - that's why I said most of the contents of the map would be hash collisions.  However, it won't matter, provided there aren't too many of these.  During the second pass, you identify which of the duplicated hash codes are hash collisions and which ones are real duplicated strings.